# permutations with restrictions the general case.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Suppose you want to create a bijective function “$f$” from the set $X$ to the set $Y$, where $|X|=|Y|$, suppose $X = \{A, B, C, D, E\}$ and $Y = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, suppose that $f(A)$ cannot be equal to 1, 2, ($f(A)\neq1, 2$), and $f(B)\neq 3, 4$, $f(C)\neq 5$, $f(D)\neq 3$, $f(E)\neq1$, how many different bijections can you create? What about the general case?

e.g. X = {A, B, C}, Y = {1, 2, 3}, $f(A)\neq1$, $f(B)\neq3, f(C)\neq 3$. then the number of possible bijections is 2: $f(A)=3, f(B)=1, f(C)=2$ and $f(A)=3, f(B)=2, f(C)=1$.

The general case would be that some elements of $X$ cannot be mapped to some subsets of $Y$.

Comment: You can solve the specific problem in the first paragraph by using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: Hi N. F. Taussig Thanks, I will try that.